# Get raw and relative path of a file uri

Tags: 8, files, uri

I have a file with an uri and I want to get its raw and relative path.

Uri: `public://videos/Test Video.mp4`
Path: `/sites/default/files/videos/Test Video.mp4`

I found already a way to do this:

```php
$file_uri = $file->getFileUri();
// public://videos/Test Video.mp4

$absolute_url = file_create_url($file_uri);
// https://www.example.com/sites/default/files/videos/Test%20Video.mp4

$relative_url = file_url_transform_relative($absolute_url);
// /sites/default/files/videos/Test%20Video.mp4

$relative_raw_url = rawurldecode($relative_url);
// /sites/default/files/videos/Test Video.mp4
```

Is this the Drupal-way? Or is there a better solution for doing this?

Comment: the question seems to invite opinions here. Is there a certain concern or worry you have about using the File API functions here?

Comment: Hi @ShawnConn! Thanks for your comment. Well I hope it's not just a thing of opions. I want to ask for a better solution if there is a better solution. I have a `$file` and I want to have the relative path. Do I really have to call 4 different File API functions?

Comment: I think I understand the concern. See below.

Answer (score 10):

I had to do this recently and found this solution using Drupal 9.1.

```
$file = File::load($fid);

$relative_file_url = $file->createFileUrl(TRUE);
$absolute_file_url = $file->createFileUrl(FALSE);
```

I found the createFileUrl() function in web/core/modules/file/src/Entity/File.php.  Maybe this would be considered "the way?"

Answer (score 3):

The "Drupal way" is always a fuzzy term because there's usually more than one answer that works.

Anyway, if you're looking for something less verbose, it would help to look at the [`File`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Entity%21File.php/class/File/8.6.x) object and it's [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Entity%21File.php/function/File%3A%3Aurl/8.6.x) method. That saves you some steps and might save you some work down the road if the old D7 [file module API functions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/8.2.x) get slated for depreciation (like `file_load` has).

Lastly, it always helps to use native PHP functions when you can since they make things more portable. To wit, [`parse_url()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.parse-url.php) allows you to slice/dice URLs to the components you want.

Putting it all together, `rawurldecode(parse_url($file->url(), PHP_URL_PATH))` pulls all your function call together for one result.

Comment: `File::url()` is deprecated as of `8.7.x` See: https://www.drupal.org/node/3019830

Answer (score 2):

```
$relative_file_url =  \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')
    ->generateAbsoluteString($uri);
```