# How to embed image field url in API response?

Tags: nodes, media

I have a content type that has a title, body, link, and image field.
Then in my php file I have the following:

```
$articles = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties(['type' => 'expand_your_world', 'status' => 1]);
```

When I check the articles variable in a JSON response, I only see the title, body, and link.

I then concluded that probably the reason why the image is not included, is because it is a reference field.

My get method looks like this:

```
$articles = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties(['type' => 'expand_your_world', 'status' => 1]);

$main_content = [];

foreach($articles as $article) {
    $fields = [
        'title' => $article->title[0]->value,
        'body' => $article->body[0]->value,
        'field_expand_link' => $article->field_expand_link[0]->uri,
        'field_expand_icon' => '',
    ];

    array_push($main_content, $fields);

}

$response = [
    'content' => $articles,
    
];
```

How do I embed the image URL in the response?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use Drupal core's JsonAPI module instead.

Comment: I wish I could. It is someone else's project which uses Restful web services.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get raw and relative path of a file uri](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277830/get-raw-and-relative-path-of-a-file-uri). Notice that you can chain `referencingFieldItem->entity` drill down through entities