# How can I get a custom module's file path in a preprocess function?

Tags: 8, media

I've got default images located in a custom module directory and I'd like to load them using `hook_preprocess_node()`. I then will pass the images to the template file.

In the screenshot, I'm loading an image into `$default_image`, which renders correctly when passed to the template file.

Instead of loading the image from an entity field, I want to read the image directly from the directory in the custom module. Clearly, the path I manually built into `$premier_tech_image` is incorrect.

> [image: screenshot]

The problem is NOT how to access the file. For example, we use code like this for JSON feeds.

```php
$module_handler = $this->moduleHandler;
$module_path = $module_handler->getModule('my_custom_module')->getPath();
$resource = $module_path . '/resources/countries.json';
```

How do I correctly pass the reference to an image located in the directory of a custom module to the template file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get raw and relative path of a file uri](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277830/get-raw-and-relative-path-of-a-file-uri)

Comment: For file objects it's either `$file->createFileUrl()` or `file_url_transform_relative(file_create_url($file_uri))`.

Comment: @leymannx that might help. I think the issue is that I need to create a consumable URI to pass to the template. The code that I used above in the example only results in a relative path to the file like "web/modules/custom/custom_module/images/premier-technology.png

Comment: Yeah, then the duplicate won't help. As you have no file object. But the answers below should give you what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Drupal URI starts with a stream wrapper like "public://" that indicates to Drupal how to handle that resource. Typically, the "public" stream wrapper is defined as "treat this resource as a local file within sites/default/files."

Your module assets are not located within sites/default/files, so they cannot use the "public" stream wrapper.

Drupal doesn't actually come out-of-the-box with a registered stream wrapper for module or theme assets. You might try installing https://www.drupal.org/project/system_stream_wrapper, which would then allow you to make a URI like `module://tableau_partners_sync/images/premier-technology.png`.

Comment: @bingo! That is exactly the issue. Do I need system_stream_wrapper to do that? I'm considering a pivot and creating an admin UI in configuration to store the files. Probably a better approach, Just a PITA to write all the code needed for that

Comment: Lots of file handling stuff in Drupal and Twig functions assume you're passing a URI parameter. Notably, image style creation requires a URI, for example. If you need to use those functions and you want to pass a module/theme asset, you'll need system_stream_wrapper. But if your use case is simple enough that you just need a plain-old URL to a static asset, you should be able to refactor your Twig to use just a relative path.

Comment: Although the issue is not solved, your answer addresses the problem with viable options. In my original question, it was clear that what I was passing to Twig is not consumable in the way that "normal" assets are. The key to this is the need to have a system_stream_wrapper. Or - punt and find a way to refactor Twig to use a relative path (I'm leaning that way in the interest of simplicity and time invested). Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 3):

Try letting Drupal generate the module path:

```
$modulePath = \Drupal::service('module_handler')->getModule('MYMODULE')->getPath();
$imagePath = $modulePath . "/images/my-image.jpg";
```

Comment: That was my first thought... and I tried it. 

` $module_handler = \Drupal::moduleHandler();
    $module_path = $module_handler->getModule('company_partners_sync')->getPath();
    $premier_tech_image = $module_path . '/images/premier-technology.png';
    $variables['default_partner_logo'] = $premier_tech_image;`

But - when it gets to twig - the file path is somehow interpreted as `files\...`

Comment: To confirm, if you `print_r($premier_tech_image);` or `kint($premier_tech_image);` in `preprocess_node()`, is the path `files/...`? Did you clear cache after updating the module path to `->getModule`?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 still has [`drupal_get_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_path/8.9.x), which is used from Drupal core modules and third-party modules for the path of files contained in modules directories. (See the code for [`ckeditor_ckeditor_css_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21ckeditor%21ckeditor.module/function/ckeditor_ckeditor_css_alter/8.9.x) or the example code given in [`hook_js_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/8.9.x).

```php
function hook_js_alter(&$javascript, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
  $javascript['core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'jquery_update') . '/jquery.js';
}
```

[Deprecate drupal_get_path() and drupal_get_filename() and replace with ExtensionList::getPath() and ExtensionList::getPathname()](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2347783) aims to deprecate the function.
At the moment I am writing this answer, its status is still *Needs work* (for Drupal 9.3.x). When it's marked as fixed, instead of `drupal_get_path('module', $module_name)`, modules will use `\Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getPath($module_name)`.

For example, the previous example hook could be rewritten in this way.

```php
function hook_js_alter(&$javascript, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
  $javascript['core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js']['data'] = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getPath('jquery_update') . '/jquery.js';
}
```

Alternatively, `\Drupal::service('extension.path.resolver')->getPath('module', $module_name)` could be used, which is what [drupal_get_path() and drupal_get_filename() have been deprecated in favor of extension listing services](https://www.drupal.org/node/2940438) suggests to use in the case the extension type is dynamically specified.